# Extract the value of a single cell in a MS excel spreadsheet from command prompt

Tags: windows, excel, powershell, command-prompt

I have spreadsheets which contain a value in cell C11.  I would like to extract this value from the command prompt in Windows 10.  Something like:

```
c:>getValue [test.xlsx]sheet1!C11  // returns "this is the data" if that string is in c11
```

What is the easiest (quickest) way to do this from the command line?

I know I can write a macro in excel and open the excel spreadsheet with the macro and then open the data spreadsheet in the macro to get and type the data, but I'd like to do this faster without having to open the full excel program.

Comment: Does your Windows 10 have [powershell] and/or [wscript]/[cscript] installed?

Comment: At least, it is not possible in one line. To do so, you would need to write a batch file which is using powershell or other script languages.

Comment: @Jeeped Yes to both.  Powershell would be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) script.

```
$filePath = "c:\tmp\test.xlsx"
$xl = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$xl.Visible = $true
if (test-path $filePath) {
  $wb = $xl.Workbooks.Open($filePath)
  $ws = $xl.WorkSheets.Item("sheet1")
  write-host $ws.name
  #$c11Val = $ws.cells.Item(11, 3).value2
  $c11Val = $ws.Range("C11").value2
  write-host $c11Val
} else {
  write-host $filePath + "WB not found"
}
$wb.close()
$xl.quit()
```

Execute on the command line like,

```
C:\TMP>powershell.exe c:\tmp\get_C11.ps1
```

That doesn't actually parse the cell, worksheet and workbook from the command line but regular expressions should be able to do that without too much problem.